# Accessing termux user environment from other consoles

Tags: terminal, ssh

I've recently started using the amazing [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) terminal app and linux environment.  It provides a wealth of full-function terminal utilities.  It would be great to be able to access these utilities from other consoles, especially when connected via `ssh` or `adb shell`.  I've managed to make some functionality available by setting my `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables to the same values used by Termux's shell, but there are permissions problems and it seems messy.

Is there a way to ssh in to a Termux session?  Termux doesn't seem to provide an ssh server package.  Even if it did, presumably that server, and thus the ssh session granted by it, would run as a separate user from the termux user, resulting in similar permissions problems.

Is there a supported way to access the Termux user environment from other consoles?

Comment: I looked at various tutorials and I could only figure out how to connect via USB (wired) tether. I couldn't figure out how to get a wireless IP for the sshd server in Termux. If anyone is having trouble finding the IP address of your phone, plug it into your PC (with USB cable) and then look for the "Default Route" on the new wired connection on your PC, that's the only way I could get it working. Also you may need "whoami" and/or "passwd" in Termux to get the username. Port defaults to 8022. PS: Tried sshuttle through the Termux sshd and my ISP still throttles it down to pathetic .5 Mbps :-/

Comment: @PJBrunet what did you try on termux to get the Ip Adress?

Comment: For getting the ip of a device, Linux-Know-How might help. As a starter I recommend Lpic1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Termux does provide the `openssh` package, which contains both the `ssh` client and the `sshd` server.

Install the package with: `apt install openssh`, then start the server with `sshd` - it will run on port 8022 by default, so connect to it with `ssh -p 8022 DEVICE_IP`, and you can find the device wifi ip using `ip addr list wlan0`.

Password authentication is not supported, so you need to setup `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

After you have connected you will run as the normal Termux user with environment variables setup correctly.

Comment: Wow, they should really mention that in the package description, which just says that it is a "Secure shell for logging in to a remote machine".

Comment: Password authentication is supported. You need to run `passwd` to set a new password for your SSH server. However, what doesn't work is usernames (i.e. everyone can log in with every username with that one password), AFAIK.

Comment: You can launch sshd on every boot using https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Boot

Comment: "wlan0" didn't give me a useable IP address

Comment: @MAChitgarha your point is essential, otherwise there is no chance to connect. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `openssh` in termux by running

```
pkg install openssh
```

and then, on the device you want to ssh from, generate a Public ID Key,

```
ssh-keygen
```

and just confirm and down change anything, then do

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and copy the output into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and restart the `sshd` server and try to ssh,

if you encounter any errors, check the `authorized_keys` file and makesure your public key is all on one line

You have to do these steps above because Termux `sshd` doesnt support password logins, (IE, `ssh user@ip_address` then entering a password)

you have to ssh into termux using

```
ssh termux-ip-here -p 8022
```

Comment: Password authentication IS now supported.

Answer (score 3):

On your knees and bow,

Ip_Address_Of_Remote_Host = 192.168.1.20

(Assuming you have generated a key on the termux machine using

ssh-keygen -t rsa

There is a space inbetween ssh-keygen and -t 
and copied the key to Remote_Host using that machines log-on details

ssh-copy-id user@192.168.1.20).

There is a space inbetween ssh-copy-id and user

You should now be able to log on to the remote  host without using a password.

ssh user@192.168.1.20

The rsa key generated above is not the key you place into the authorized_keys file on the termux machine.

The issue is getting the

id_rsa.pub

file from your Remote machine to the termux

~/.ssh/authorized_keys

file on the Local system (phone) the solution I used was scp, this command confuses a lot of people but if viewed from the position that it is just a cp command it's mysticism vanishes

**cp file_to_copy  where_to_copy_file**

This command is run from the Termux machine (phone)

**scp user@192.168.1.20:/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys**

There is a space inbetween id_rsa.pub and ~/

The path to your .ssh directory may be different just make sure it is the correct path you enter into he above command.

If you still have trouble logging on navigate to the

**/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/sshd_config file**

Activate these two key pairs

**ChallengeResponseAuthentication no**

**PubkeyAuthentication yes**

Comment: For anybody with a slight understanding of SSH this should be straight forward for those who are new to GNU/Linux paths are what you need to be focused on. My next port of call is to see if X forwarding is possible for then it opens up the possibility of using the productivity suits on your desktop but writing to the termux machine, let me expand you will be able to use LibraOffice software on the termux machine but have it displayed on the desktop without lagging/latency this is the power of GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

These are Android commands to run on Termux and setup a SSH client and server,
allowing to connect from your desktop to your Android and vice-versa.
This does not cover the SSH server and client set up on your desktop computer.

**Using the SSH server**
https://termux.com/ssh.html

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install openssh
```

Here you can create a password for your keys and use it to connect to your computer, if you like
a password. Otherwise, leave them in blank and no passwords are required, other than your
DESKTOP user computer password.

**How can I set up password-less SSH login?**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa
```

This allows you to connect from your ANDROID to your DESKTOP by SSH connection without
your ANDROID user password (as passwords are not supported by termux sshd server)

**3 Steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id**
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub your_desktop_ssh_user@YOUR.DESKTOP.IP.ADDRESS
```

This allows you to connect from your DESKTOP to your ANDROID by SSH connection without
your ANDROID user password (if you want to use your's computer user password, skip this command)

1. First Option
   **Accessing termux user environment from other consoles**
   [Accessing termux user environment from other consoles](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154756/accessing-termux-user-environment-from-other-consoles)

   ```
   scp your_desktop_ssh_user@YOUR.DESKTOP.IP.ADDRESS:~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
2. Second Option
   **How do I add SSH Keys to authorized_keys file?**
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/46424/how-do-i-add-ssh-keys-to-authorized-keys-file

   ```
   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh your_desktop_ssh_user@YOUR.DESKTOP.IP.ADDRESS "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
   ```

**Scripts and notes for setting up and using SSHd on your Android device using Termux**
https://github.com/tomhiggins/TermuxSSHDsetup

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**ssh blank passphrase but still asking for it**
https://serverfault.com/questions/845623/ssh-blank-passphrase-but-still-asking-for-it

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Start the server by executing sshd (which will start it on the default port 8022)
and run `logcat -s 'syslog:*'` to view the log output from the server process.
Execute pkill sshd to stop the server.

```
logcat -s 'syslog:*'
pkill sshd
sshd
```

---

Finally, connecting from one to another and vice-versa:

Connecting from your ANDROID to your DESKTOP (the usage of your DESKTOP user password can be optional)

```
ssh your_desktop_ssh_user@YOUR.DESKTOP.IP.ADDRESS
```

Connecting from your DESKTOP to your ANDROID (must not to use your ANDROID user password)

**Since Termux is a single-user system you may connect as any user - regardless
of your specified username you will login as the only Termux user available.**

**The Termux sshd binary does not support password logins, so a key needs to be authorized in
`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` before connecting. Use ssh-keygen to generate a new one if desired.**

```
ssh -p 8022 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa IP.OF.YOUR.ANDROID
```

(ANDROID) **If you still have trouble logging on navigate to file and activate these two key pairs:**
`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

---

Extra: Locking and unlocking the file system from read-only to read-write and vice-versa.

**How to copy files to an Android emulator’s data directory with ‘adb push’**
https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-copy-files-android-device-emulator-adb-push-read-only-error

```
mount -o rw,remount rootfs /
```

Revert the changes back after finishing the changes!

```
cat /proc/mounts
mount -o ro,remount rootfs /
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, I build `termux` app and then `adb shell` to access termux console from **PC** without requiring root.

*The prefix below of `[PC]~ $`, `[ADB]~ $` and `[ADB's BASH]~ $` indicates where the command type from.*

1. In Android settings, enable **Developer options**, toggle on **USB debugging**, and uninstall existing termux app for all users. And of course, **the existing termux data will loss.**
2. Clone termux source code, `[PC]~ $ git clone https://github.com/termux/termux-app`
3. Open that project in Android Studio, plug-in phone cable, select phone device from menu then direct run or build it as debug apk which allow you use `run-as` without root.
4. `[PC]~ $ adb shell`
5. `[ADB]~ $ run-as com.termux`
6. `[ADB]~ $ cd files/usr/bin`
7. If not yet install `bash` and `vim`, either go to Android device to install, or `[ADB]~ $ export PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:$PATH` first then `pkg install bash` and `pkg install vim`.
8. `./bash` to launch bash shell session.
9. `[ADB's BASH]~ $ vim ~/.bashrc` and put this 2 lines which set environment when launch new bash session: `PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:$PATH` and `export LD_PRELOAD=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libtermux-exec.so`
10. `[ADB's BASH]~ $ . ~/.bashrc` to take effect immediately.
11. Use `rsync` command, e.g. `[ADB's BASH]~ $ rsync -rvtP --remove-source-files source_dir foo@IP:/home/foo/Downloads/` to transfer file between Android and PC. (Note: Source directory don't trailing with `/`, and need `find source_dir -type d -empty -delete` after done to remove empty directories) . Alternatively use `[PC]~ $ adb exec-out run-as com.termux cat '/data/user/0/com.termux/.bashrc' > ~/Downloads/.bashrc` to pull file from Android to PC.
12. To quit, <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or `[ADB's BASH]~ $ exit`. `[ADB]~ $ ./bash`
    to re-enter new bash session.
13. For unknown reason, first time access will no internet, you need launch termux app in android device manually once, after that can exit termux app.